# Bevel ruins the geometry instead of creating new one

Tags: geometry, bevel

I tried to bevel an edge, but it acts weirdly, snapping the nearby point.
The wireframe shows that everything is ok, but the shading looks like a complete mess.
I'm a total newbie, so I think I'm doing something wrong here, any advice or a solution would be much appreciated, thank you.[image]
[image]

Comment: You showed there what you do not want, but what is it that you want? How exactly would you suggest should Blender connect a beveled edge to the surrounding edges? The problem is you split something up into several edges/faces/vertices while the connected edges and faces are not beveled... beveling does not disconnect edges from their surrounding geometry, so the question is how do you want it to look?

Comment: Pardon me? Of course it disconnect. Blender usually does new nicely calculated geometry out of your bevel with no problems, the detail I'm working now has several similar edges I have modified, except this one edge. Added an image for clarification.

Comment: Splitting vertices is not automatically disconnecting. The resulting geometry is still connected. The difference between the "work fine" version and the one you had to rebuild is the angle between edges and faces (and also the number of edges). When you bevel edges, the split vertices slide along the connecting edges opposite to the bevel the same length and keep the connection to the start and end vertex of the bevel. In the area where it does not work the problem is actually two things:

Comment: The corner vertex is connected with edges in opposite directions making it impossible to stay in the same plane when following all directions. It would slightly be better if there was no separating edge between the two adjacent faces in the same plane (like you have in the "work fine" bottom right, otherwise that wouldn't have worked either), but still the faces below the beveled edge form an "inner" corner, which gets overlapped when the vertex sliding away from the bevel connects to the outer vertex of the bevel. I'm sorry I don't how to explain it well in English.